# Using an arc in a continuous path

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I'd like one of the edges of a "rectangle" to be an arc. I had hoped that an `arc` could be used similarly to `--`, and that `cycle` would close the *whole* path, but apparently it only closes the arc. How would I get rid of line down the middle? Here is the code I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\chamberheight}{4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\chamberwidth}{5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\curverad}{4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\phibase}{asin(\chamberheight/2/\curverad)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\phif}{180+\phibase}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\phii}{180-\phibase}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xin}{\curverad*cos(\phibase)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cellwidth}{0.4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cellheight}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\initialx}{\xin-\curverad+0.05}


  \draw[smooth,thick,line join=round] (0,-\chamberheight/2) --
    ++(\chamberwidth,0) -- ++(0,\chamberheight) -- ++(-\chamberwidth,0)
    ++(\xin,-2) ++(\phii:\curverad) arc (\phii:\phif:\curverad) --
    cycle;

  \foreach \x in {-18,-6,6,18}{ 
    \draw[smooth, line join=round, thick, fill=white, 
            rotate around={\x:(\xin,0)}]
      (\initialx,-\cellwidth/2) -- ++(-\cellheight,0) --
      ++(0,\cellwidth) -- ++(\cellheight,0);}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just drawing the rectangle and then drawing the version with the arc as well. If you cut out the relevant line, it works fine.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\chamberheight}{4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\chamberwidth}{5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\curverad}{4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\phibase}{asin(\chamberheight/2/\curverad)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\phif}{180+\phibase}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\phii}{180-\phibase}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xin}{\curverad*cos(\phibase)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cellwidth}{0.4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cellheight}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\initialx}{\xin-\curverad+0.05}


  \draw [smooth,thick,line join=round]
  (0,-\chamberheight/2)  --
  ++(\chamberwidth,0) --
  ++(0,\chamberheight) --
  ++(-\chamberwidth,0)
  arc (\phii:\phif:\curverad)  --
    cycle;

  \foreach \x in {-18,-6,6,18}{
    \draw[smooth, line join=round, thick, fill=white,
            rotate around={\x:(\xin,0)}]
      (\initialx,-\cellwidth/2) -- ++(-\cellheight,0) --
      ++(0,\cellwidth) -- ++(\cellheight,0);}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: arc closure]

Note that `rounded rectangle` could draw the initial outline as a single `\node` operation, if that would work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't clear on `arc` command. I guess that's what happens when you learn syntax only from examples without consulting the manual :).